# How do you modify manytomanyfield in form in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to change the value of a many-to-many field in a Django form?

Preferably, I would like to change the value within the `def form_valid` of my `Modelview`. Here is a part of the `form_valid` in my view that I am having trouble with:

```
lesson = Lesson.objects.all().first()

for i in lesson.weekday.all():
    form.instance.weekday.add(i)
    form.instance.save()
```

Here, `weekday` is a many-to-many field. However, the form saves the `"submitted"` values of the `weekday` by the user, and not the changed one as shown in the above code. Interestingly, the below code works, although it is not a many-to-many field:

```
form.instance.name = lesson.name
form.instance.save()
```

Comment: Can you show us the full code in your `form_valid` method?

Comment: Thank you for you comment, Tonio. However, my form_valid is extremely long, and there are a lot of unrelated code with this issue. I looked over my form_valid function again, but there is really nothing much to add other than the code I wrote above. If you ask for something else, then I would try to edit it into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are running the code before calling the super method. The code in the super method can look like this:

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

When  `form.save()` runs clear all ManyToMany related values and sets the form values.

Probably you need run your code after calling the super method:

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    # some code here...
    return_value = super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)
    lesson = Lesson.objects.all().first()
    for i in lesson.weekday.all():
        self.object.weekday.add(i)
        # self.object.save() # Dont need call save here

    return return_value
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. Is it recommended to always put the super method before typing the actual code? I don't know why a simple replacement of the super method would solve this issue...

Comment: @codebuilder, after or before depens on each case. In general I write before to call the super method. But, in this example,  you first set the m2m values, and then, when you call super, the code runs the `form.save()` , and in a "ModelForm" the save method reset all the m2m relations.

 I recommend everyone to try to know whow the framework works internally, inspecing the inherit methods like this `form_valid`.